# TableView being loaded before fetching data

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I working with an application that retrieves data from `HealthKit` and then store them in an array. What I'm trying to do is load my `tableViewController` with the data in that array. But unfortunately when I run the application the table appears empty.

To be more clear, I have a method that do coding to retrieve the list of required data, if fills an array (which declared at the top of the class) with these fetched data.

What I did is I called this function in the `viewDidLoad` function, and I printed out the array but it was empty, so I moved the call of the method to the function `viewDidAppear` and printed out the array. The array successfully filled with the data but I still have a problem with dynamically fill the rows with the data of this array. It still appears blank. The problem as I understood is that the table view is being loaded before the array is filled with data. I tried another solution by calling the method `self.tableView.reloadData()` but no luck with that.

Could anyone please give me any idea to solve this issue?

UPDATE:

Here is the `viewDidLoad` function:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    authorizeHealthKit()
    updateLastGlucoRecords()
    println("\(glucoReadings)")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

}
```

And this the `viewDidAppear` function:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    updateLastGlucoRecords()
    println("Hereeeee2:   \(glucoReadings)")
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Here is where the table should dynamically be loaded by the data:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! UITableViewCell

    let df = NSDateFormatter()
    let tf = NSDateFormatter()

    df.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    tf.dateFormat = "hh:mm:ss"

    let readingDateTime = dates[indexPath.row]

    let dateTabel = cell.viewWithTag(100) as! UILabel!
    let timeLabel = cell.viewWithTag(101) as! UILabel!
    let readingLabel = cell.viewWithTag(102) as! UILabel!
    let indicator = cell.viewWithTag(103) as UIView!


    dateTabel.text = df.stringFromDate(readingDateTime)
    timeLabel.text = tf.stringFromDate(readingDateTime)


    let reading = readings[indexPath.row]

    let doubleReading = getRecordDouble(reading)
    readingLabel.text = reading
    let sCase = recordCase(doubleReading!)
    switch (sCase) {
    case "Very low": indicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    case "Too low": indicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    case "Normal": indicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
    case "Too high": indicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellowColor()
    case "Very High": indicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
    case "Danger": indicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    default: indicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
    }

    return cell
}
```

And lastly here is the method that retrieves the data from `HealthKit`:

```
func updateLastGlucoRecords()
{
    // 1. Construct an HKSampleType for weight
    let sampleType = HKSampleType.quantityTypeForIdentifier(HKQuantityTypeIdentifierBloodGlucose)
    // 2. Call the method to read the most recent weight sample
    self.healthManager.readRecent10GlucoseReadings(sampleType, completion: {(allReadings, error) -> Void in
        println()
        if (error != nil) {
            println("Error reading glucose readings from HealthKit Store: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return;
        }

        var glucoseLocalizedString = self.kUnknownString;
        self.glucoses = allReadings as? [HKQuantitySample]
        for reading in self.glucoses! {

            if let record = reading.quantity {
                glucoseLocalizedString = "\(record)"
                let dateTimeRecorded = reading.startDate
                self.glucoReadings.append(glucoseLocalizedString)
                self.glucoDates.append(dateTimeRecorded)
                println("Reading: \(self.glucoReadings), Date: \(self.glucoDates)")
            }
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

            })
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Post some code please

Comment: @gonjidev Please have a look now, I've updated the question

Comment: You are using `self.glucoReadings`, `self.glucoses` and `self.glucoDates` inside `updateLastGlucoRecords`  but in the datasource method you are reading data from `dates` and `readings`.

Comment: @gonjidev oh, that is stupid, I fixed that now but unfortunately the problem still exist!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, the query you are using in HealthKit includes a completion handler. This handler is called when the query completes, and that is where you should call reloadData.

Since the HealthKit call is asynchronous, you cannot rely on the array being populated in `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidLoad`.

Comment: Thanks @michaelL, I checked that but also no results!

Comment: After fixing some stupid mistakes, I tried your solution and actually it is the  the correct one, thanks too much

Answer (score 2):

Try to call `self.tableView.reloadData()` in the main thread after your array is filled:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
      self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

And don't forget to make sure that your `datasource` methods are correctly implemented.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, I tried that but unfortunately didn't work

Comment: Please add some code to your question. Mainly the code from your datasource methods